# Susy grid - any (easy?) way to make 'columns' the same height?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

Getting my feet wet with Susy/sass/haml etc (using adjusted middleman - with latest susy from master branch)

Have this in grid.css.scss

```
@import 'susy';

$total-columns  : 8;
$column-width   : 4em;
$gutter-width   : 0em;
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;

$break-max      : 12;

$container-style: magic;

// Container
.page {
  @include container($total-columns, $break-max);
}

// Layout

.header {
  @include at-breakpoint($break-max) {
    @include pad(1,1);
  }
}

.pagenav {
  clear: both;
  @include at-breakpoint($break-max) {
    @include pad(1,1);
  }
}

.main {
  clear: both; 
  .main-left {  
    @include span-columns($total-columns omega);
    @include at-breakpoint(10) {
      @include span-columns(7);  
    } 
  }
  .main-right {  
    @include span-columns($total-columns omega);  
    @include at-breakpoint(10) {
      @include span-columns(3 omega);  
    }        
  }
  @include at-breakpoint($break-max) {
    @include pad(1,1);
  }
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  @include at-breakpoint($break-max) {
    @include pad(1,1);
  }
}
```

this snippet comes from site.css.scss

```
.main {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.main-left {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.main-right {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

.body background is black...

Now when content in main-left is larger than main-right I see a black square on the bottom right...
Any way I can make that bottom right #eee i.o.w. main-right the same height (dynamic) as main-left - or have the .main background to apply...???

Thanks

Peter

PS Somebody with more credits should make a Susy tag in stackoverflow...

Comment: Equal-height columns are really a distinct issue from Susy. There is no perfect answer in CSS, but there are several workarounds including using background to fake it, using table display, etc. Any of the options will work with Susy.

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to SO :) It would be a good idea to accept an answer to allow other people with similar questions to know that this solved your problem(not to mention you get a badge!).

Answer (score 4):

```
#main {
  display: table;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.main-left,
.main-right{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.main-left {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.main-right {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

This will make the two divs match each other as if they were adjacent table cells.
Don't worry, this doesn't qualify as using tables for layout, it's cool for columns, and it's not caused me any problems.
Of course, shitty old browsers don't support it, but you could use a .js script like [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to patch it where necessary.

Comment: I checked out display: table; and see its use but the @include pad(1,1); is what is causing the problem... I don't want those 'padding columns to take on the color of .main, those have to be black... So it really is .main-right that has to stretch... or .main-left in the odd case that there is less content on the left than on the right...

Comment: You can use `squish(1,1)` instead of `pad(1,1)` if you need the extra added to margins rather than padding.

Comment: OK got it figured out... combining both display: table-cell & squish.
Thank you very much. [Eric, Susy looks really great :-) ]