# Susy matching column heights

Tags: css, susy-compass

New to Susy. I have a 12-column grid with side-by-side content areas: content-left: span-columns(3,12); content-right: span-columns(9 omega, 12). both content areas must have equal height, matching the area with the longest content. Ordinarily I'd use a clearfix in this situation, but that doesn't seem to apply to susy grids. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Susy grid - any (easy?) way to make 'columns' the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026053/susy-grid-any-easy-way-to-make-columns-the-same-height)

Answer (score 1):

Clearfix works fine with Susy, but clearfix won't give you equal height columns. It only forces the container to clear the columns. CSS doesn't actually have a good solution for equal height, but there are [various workarounds](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) you can try. Susy won't have any affect, for better or worse. All Susy really does is float columns and set their width.