# Susy grid same height

Tags: css, susy, susy-sass

I have this susy grid and I would like to have all its columns the same height, I tried adding the display: table technique but I can't get it to work. I tried the suggestions posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026053/susy-grid-any-easy-way-to-make-columns-the-same-height) but that didn't get me anywhere either, I created this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ryansegus/pen/qbvmad) to see if someone can take a look.

```css
@import "susy";

$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  gutters: 0,
);

.container{
  @include container(600px center);
}
.mTable {
  display:table;
  > .col {
 @include span(6);
    display:table-cell;
    &:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:gray;
  }
    &:nth-child(even){
    background-color:lightgray;
  }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: If you look at the compiled CSS code you are mixing `display:table` and `float`...that's probably the issue.

Comment: yep, float comes from the mixin span, I wonder if I can overide that or another elegant solution.

Comment: Well...flexbox of course - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dGrRvd

Comment: Beautiful! thanks a lot!